# Extract certain characters from list and convert them into a character vector

Tags: r, list, dplyr, stringr

I have a column in my data frame that is a list of characters. This is the column `categories`

```
str(df)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ categories:List of 4
  ..$ : chr  "Tex-Mex" "Mexican" "Fast Food" "Restaurants"
  ..$ : chr  "Hawaiian" "Restaurants" "Barbeque"
  ..$ : chr  "Restaurants" "Italian" "Seafood"
  ..$ : chr  "Restaurants" "Mexican" "American (Traditional)"
 $ name      : chr  "Taco Bell" "Ohana Hawaiian BBQ" "Carrabba's Italian Grill" "Don Tequila"
 $ type      : chr  "business" "business" "business" "business"
```

Here is a `dput` of the first four rows:

```
structure(list(categories = list(c("Tex-Mex", "Mexican", "Fast Food", 
"Restaurants"), c("Hawaiian", "Restaurants", "Barbeque"), c("Restaurants", 
"Italian", "Seafood"), c("Restaurants", "Mexican", "American (Traditional)"
)), name = c("Taco Bell", "Ohana Hawaiian BBQ", "Carrabba's Italian Grill", 
"Don Tequila"), type = c("business", "business", "business", 
"business")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .Names = c("categories", "name", "type"))
```

I want to extract some of the values from that list so that these values are the only ones that remain in that vector.

For example, I want to filter out all values that are not "Mexican" and not "Restaurants". So the only values that remain says "Mexican" and "Restaurants". To do so I tried this solution:

```
df_test <- df %>% unnest(categories) %>% 
          filter(str_detect(categories, "Mexican")
                (str_detect(categories, "Restaurants")) %>% 
          nest(categories)
```

But the result looks like this:

```
str(df_test)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ name: chr  "Taco Bell" "Ohana Hawaiian BBQ" "Carrabba's Italian Grill" "Don Tequila"
 $ type: chr  "business" "business" "business" "business"
 $ data:List of 4
  ..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ categories: chr  "Mexican" "Restaurants"
  ..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ categories: chr "Restaurants"
  ..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ categories: chr "Restaurants"
  ..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ categories: chr  "Restaurants" "Mexican"
```

The problem is, that after that the column is no character vector like the `type` column.

Is there a possibility to filter out those characters so that after the procedure the column is a normal character vector like the `name` and the `type` column?
I don ´t want to replace the values/rows I removed through this procedure. So if there are no "Mexican" or "Restaurants" in a certain row, the row will be removed.

Used packages: 
`dplyr` 
`stringr`

Comment: Please include all packages that you are using...Not just `dplyr`

Comment: Also, you would probably do better to add a fuller dataset (one or two additional variables) as well as present your desired outcome for that dataset. For example, iIt is unclear whether you want to drop all rows that do not contain "mexican" in this column or whether you want to replace that value with an NA.

Comment: Why are you using `str_detect` there? You can simply do `df %>% unnest() %>% filter(categories == 'Mexican')`

Comment: I want to filter out more than one value. If I do it this way some rows will be multiplied.

Comment: So just do `df %>% unnest() %>% filter(categories %in% c('Mexican', 'Restaurants'))`

Comment: THX, but It´s the same thing. If I use that code the rows that contain both values will be doubled.  If I `nest()` the `categories` after that I get the same result as `str(df_test)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `lapply` to subset the list

```
lapply(df1$categories, function(x) x[x %in% c("Mexican", "Restaurants")])

[[1]]
[1] "Mexican"     "Restaurants"

[[2]]
[1] "Restaurants"

[[3]]
[1] "Restaurants"

[[4]]
[1] "Restaurants" "Mexican"
```

Adding row with no matching criteria to filter row

```
df1 <- rbind(df1, c(list("Nothing to match"), "drop me", "business"))
df1$categories <- lapply(df1$categories, function(x) x[x %in% c("Mexican", "Restaurants")])
df1[sapply(df1$categories, length) > 0, ]
```

Collapsing list into character string

```
df1$categories <- sapply(df1$categories, function(x) paste(sort(x[x %in% c("Mexican", "Restaurants")]), collapse=" "))
df1[nchar(df1$categories) > 0, ]

# A tibble: 4 x 3
           categories                     name     type
                <chr>                    <chr>    <chr>
1 Mexican Restaurants                Taco Bell business
2         Restaurants       Ohana Hawaiian BBQ business
3         Restaurants Carrabba's Italian Grill business
4 Mexican Restaurants              Don Tequila business
```

Comment: THX, it works but the vector is still a list, not a character.

Comment: @Banjo do you want to paste all remaining entries into a single string?

Comment: Yes, the characters should be one vector.

Comment: @Banjo added example to collapse list into a single string